# SharePoint 2016 - Event ID 8313 - A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, managed-metadata-service, minrole, service-endpoint

This is in a SharePoint 2016 MinRole Farm (1 Front-End with Dist Cache and 1 Application with Search).

On WFE server I see Error on Event Viewer from 5 AM to 6 PM hourly:

```
Event ID 8313 User: DOMAIN\Pool - A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure
Process Name: w3wp
Process ID: 1400
AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/########/ROOT-1-###########
AppDomain ID: 2
Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:0f11b87f6c7b45bf8ed09e5ede533b44#authority=urn:uuid:b10dabc24c664df1805a96c4d49ae4c7&authority=https://AppServer:32844/Topology/topology.svc
Active Endpoints: 1
Failed Endpoints:1
Affected Endpoint: http://WFEServer:32843/0f11b87f6c7b45bf8ed09e5ede533b44/MetadataWebService.svc
```

When I click on the Affected EndPoint URL it shows the Service page, which means the Endpoint is working properly as this [reference link explains](https://gai3kannan.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/a-failure-was-reported-when-trying-to-invoke-a-service-application-endpointfailure-solution-step-by-step/).

I have no failing jobs and have been researching but don't find any answer to this Error. I did look at several questions that are posted already in stack-exchange related to EndPoint Failure. I have a test environment and I don't have this error showing up in Event Viewer, so this is only happening in this production farm.

*Any idea about how to stop this error flooding Event Viewer*?

Answer (score 3):

We had the same kind of problem in one of the farm. What we did:

- Stop the MMS service on the effected server (wfe) ( from central admin > system settings > manage services on server)
- Check IIS and make sure their is no app pool and Site enter for MMS ( under the Services WebSite). if any entry exist for Managed Meta data service, please delete it.
- If not then start the MMS service on the server ( from central admin > system settings > manage services on server)

On a side note, sometime IIS reset clear that corruption as well.